# AngularJS router code not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have checked Stack overflow and many other blogs but I was not able to resolve the routing issue that I have in my AngularJS code. I'm not getting any error but the routing doesn't seem to be happening  at all. 
Can anyone please help me fix this issue?
The main index.html is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>AngularJS Routing example</title>
</head>

<body data-ng-app="sampleApp">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#AddNewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
                <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div data-ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have uploaded the complete code to Plunker [AngularJS Routing](http://plnkr.co/edit/gtb70DO7w14ENBa33xNk)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Smitha

Comment: use `ng-href` instead of href, just a suggestion

Comment: The ng-href didn't work too :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plunker doesnt work because of missing angular-route.js. But What can I see you have forgotten to give angular dependency - ngRoute

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

This oficial tutorial shows how to use the router https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

I have updated your plunker with changes which works

http://plnkr.co/edit/BBG3XH3akxfAKMzjT71E?p=preview

Main problem - version mishmash - uploaded angular - 1.3.x, uploaded angular-rout - 1.2-x linked angular to html - 1.0-7

I have changed them to cdn 1.3.3

Next thing - wrong links to templates - even if it could work on localhost - in plunker there cant be / on begining of templates name.

I have changed also links it should start # in ng-href.

Thats basically all.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'm sorry the angular-route.js was not saved in plunker. But I originally had it. Please see the updated code. Even with this change its not working.

Comment: I have edited answer and provided new information with working plunker

Comment: Your changes work like a charm. Thank you very much. Could you please let me know where you made the version changes?

Comment: You are welcome. 

I have changed them in bottom of index.html. I used uris from http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/. You can use cdns also in your localhost development. But after all, in the future you should look about http://bower.io/ and then about http://gulpjs.com/ it will boost your javascript development.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help in fixing the issue and for all your valuable inputs. Appreciate it very much.

Comment: Do I need to use `ui-router` if i upgrade to angular 1.3.x from 1.2.x? Is `angular-route.js` no longer sufficient?  I am seeing a similar problem where my links all fall through to `$routeProvider.otherwise` when I migrated from 1.2 to 1.3, but my `angular`, `angular-route`, and `angular-resource` are all 1.3.15, and I am not using `ui-router`.  When I removed the #s in index.html the problem didn't happen anymore, but that doesn't seem like the right solution. I do not have / before my routing paths.

Comment: No you can still use ngRouter, it is fine for many application. Can you post your exact problem into new question and give link here, I will look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove `/` from templateUrl

```
sampleApp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/AddNewOrder', {
    templateUrl : 'add_order.html',
    controller : 'AddOrderController'
}).when('/ShowOrders', {
    templateUrl : 'show_orders.html',
    controller : 'ShowOrdersController'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/AddNewOrder'
});
```

} ]);

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed the "/" but it doesn't seem to be working still. Please see the updated plunker.